# Exception handling within loop. Why does this code give a not all code paths return a value error?

Tags: c#

```
public static Boolean CanParseStringToInt(String s)
    {
        Boolean retry = false;
        int n = 0;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                n = int.Parse(s);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (!retry)
                {
                    retry = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        while (retry);
    }
```

I'm targeting .Net 4.0 and using VS2012. The code is just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler can't absolutely tell if a piece of code will eventually return a value.  Look at the [Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) for an example of the difficulty.

If you restructure the code like this, it should behave the same way but will fix the error:

```
public static Boolean CanParseStringToInt(String s)
{
    Boolean retry = false;
    int n = 0;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            n = int.Parse(s);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (!retry)
            {
                retry = true;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (retry);

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is not smart enough to know that you will eventually return inside the loop.

I would add this line at the end of the method:

```
throw new InvalidOperationException("Should not have reached here.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything after your `while` loop.

Not sure what this method is used for, but I would suggest `Int32.TryParse()` instead of this implementation.

Comment: The use of the method is irrelevant, it's just for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no return statement in the `if` block inside the `catch` block.  Hence the body of the loop is assumed to execute.  This means the `while` condition also executes and hence the compiler assumes it can return false.  This means there must also be a return following the `while` statement

Answer (score 0):

In your catch the else condition returns but the if does not, it instead does assignment. There's also no return outside of your while.

```
       catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!retry)
            {
                retry = true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

In general I prefer to write retry logic like below;

```
 for (int i = 0; i < retries; i++)
 {
     try
     {
         //do stuff that could throw
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Thread.Sleep(500);
         if (i == retries - 1)
         {
             throw new Exception(e.Message);
         }
     }
  }
```

Also, after a second look at your code it seems like you're re writing `int.TryParse(string input, out int output)`